# error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. no se encuentra el recurso

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webservice

Estoy realizando mantenimiento a un programa que trabaja con web service y el patron MCV. accedia sin inconveniente solo estaba debugeando ya que necesitaba ver lo que hacia el programa, incluí código comentando y luego lo quitaba cuando volví a ejecutar sin modificar nada, me arrojo este mensaje..**Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.** me asegure de darle Ctrl+Z para devolver todos los cambios desde el inicio y aun así nada

**ESTO ES LO QUE ME SALE EN EL NAVEGADOR** [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**QUE NECESITO PROPORCIONARLES PARA QUE ME AYUDEN ES URGENTE!**

**ESTE ES EL Index.cshtml**

```
    <div id="sorter" class="styleSorter">
    Ordenado por:
    <select id="cbOrdenar" class="styleOrdenar">
        <option value="D">Nombre</option>
        <option value="A">SAP</option>
        <option value="S" selected="selected">Stock</option>
        <option value="P">Precio</option>
    </select>
    <select id="cbSentido" class="styleOrdenar">
        <option value="A">Ascendentemente</option>
        <option value="D" selected="selected">Descendentemente</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="autenticar">
</div>
<div id="idHeaderCompacta" class="headerCompacta">
    <table class="tblHeaderCompacta">
        <tr>
            <td id="tdSAP" class="HeaderOrderTable" style="width: 85px" onclick="sorterTabla('A')">
                SAP
                <img style="display: inline; width: 10px;" id="imgSAP" alt="Ordenar por Precio" src="../../ImagenesMateriales/Emptypix.png" />
            </td>
            <td id="tdDescripcion" class="HeaderOrderTable" style="width: 400px" onclick="sorterTabla('D')">
                @Html.Raw("Descripción")
                <img style="display: inline; width: 10px;" id="imgDescripcion" alt="Ordenar por Descripción"
                    src="../../ImagenesMateriales/Emptypix.png" />
            </td>
            <td id="tdPrecio" class="HeaderOrderTable" style="width: 120px; text-align: right;"
                onclick="sorterTabla('P')">
                Precio
                <img style="display: inline; width: 10px;" id="imgPrecio" alt="Ordenar por Precio"
                    src="../../ImagenesMateriales/Emptypix.png" />
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td id="tdDisponibilidad" class="HeaderOrderTable" style="text-align: right; width: 160px"
                onclick="sorterTabla('S')">
                Disponibilidad
                <img style="display: inline; width: 10px;" id="imgDisponibilidad" alt="Ordenar por Disponibilidad"
                    src="../../Content/images/DownArrow.png" />
            </td>
            <td style="width: 35px">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="resultado" class="cuerpo">
</div>
<div id="PoupInformacionStock">
    <div id="loading3" style="text-align: center; z-index: 3000">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/loading.gif")" alt="Cargando" />
    </div>
    <div id="Info">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divPopupInformacionTienda">
    <div id="result">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divProveedores" class="cssWindowProveedor">
</div>
<div id="divBarras" class="cssWindowBarras">
</div>
<div id="divCaracteristicas" class="cssWindowCaracteristicas">
</div>
<div id="TipInformacion" class="cssWindowStock">
</div>
<div id="loading2" style="text-align: center; position: fixed; bottom: 55px; width: 100%;"
    align="center">
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/loading.gif")" alt="Cargando" />
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div id="sinResultados" class="sinResultados">
    No existen registros que coincidan con la información especificada.
</div>
```

Comment: Muestra el codigo completo al que le metiste mano. En algun lado dejaste algo dirigido a otra direccion

Comment: Ya lo hice, pero la parte que coloque dudo mucho que sea el error, ya que debe ser en una view o controlador y esas carpetas no las toque! necesito ayuda por favor

Comment: No lo agreges como respuesta, puedes editar tu publicacion

Comment: ya edite la publicacion amigo

Comment: No modificaste el index o el boostraping de la aplicación?

Comment: no lo mofique, alli anexo el index, otra cosa tengo la misma aplicación pero una versión anterior y si funciona sin inconveniente compare los archivos y la version nueva tiene el global incluido en la carpeta view, pero estan iguales